# Storing Connection String in a String

Tags: java, database, string, connection-string

How can I store my connection string 
**eg: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@local:testserver","scott","tiger"** 
in a String variable and pass that string to the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about

```
String connString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@local:testserver";
```

pass that in to your connection:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,"someUsername","somePassword");
```

Theres a tutorial on how to connect to oracle databases with Java [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.be/2012/04/java-program-to-connect-oracle-database.html)

Comment: @Asif what exactly is not working? its extremely hard to tell by what is wrong if you just say "its not working"

Comment: Sorry :)Thanks very much. I was forgetting the commas.

Answer (score 1):

Thin name service syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA

If you need to supply other Oracle-specific connection properties then you need to use the long TNSNAMES style. The TNS format is:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=HOSTNAME)(protocol=tcp)(port=PORT))(connect_data=(service_name=SERVICENAME)(server=SHARED)))

Answer (score 1):

You can istantiate a String like this:

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@local:server";
```

and then use this String for connection, like Thousand wrote.

Anyway, I think that this code can't be reusable. It should be better to create a class connection like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConectionTest {

    static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {

        String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@local:server";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "usertest";
        String password = "pwdtest";

        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, userName,password);

        return conn;
    }
}
```

And then use the connection anywhere.